# How to combine TSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-editor

I have four TSV files like this:

file_1:

```
abc \t 1
def \t 3
ghi \t 5
```

file_2:

```
abc \t 10
def \t 4
ghi \t 7
```

file_3:

```
abc \t 8
def \t 5
ghi \t 1
```

file_4:

```
abc \t 4
def \t 2
ghi \t 1
```

I want to combine those TSV files into the one TSV like this:

```
dataset \t file_1 \t file_2 \t file_3 \t file_4
abc \t 1 \t 10 \t 8 \t 4
def \t 3 \t 4 \t 5 \t 2
ghi \t 5 \t 7 \t 1 \t 1
```

How I can get that?

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} 
    FNR==1{f = f "\t" FILENAME} 
    NR==FNR{a[$1] = $2} 
    NR!=FNR{a[$1] = a[$1] "\t" $2} 
    END{printf "dataset%s\n", f; for(i in a) print i, a[i]}
  ' file_{1..4}
dataset file_1  file_2  file_3  file_4
def     3       4       5       2
abc     1       10      8       4
ghi     5       7       1       1
```

If you need sorted output, either pipe the result through `sort` or (assuming GNU awk 4.0 or above) add `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"` in either the `BEGIN` or `END` block.

---

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ cat file_{1..4} | mlr --tsv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output --quote-none \
    nest --implode --values --across-records -f 2 --nested-fs tab
abc     1       10      8       4
def     3       4       5       2
ghi     5       7       1       1
```

With a sufficiently new version of Miller you can use the shorthand `nest --ivar tab -f 2` in place of `nest --implode --values --across-records -f 2 --nested-fs tab`

Comment: When I use \ before `nest` this command is doesn't work, but when I delete \ before `nest` this command is works

Comment: @Lulu'Nisrina the \ is a *line continuation character* - I split the command over several lines to make it easier to read. If you use it, it **must** be the very last character on its line (with no spaces after it for example).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr -N --tsv nest --ivar ";" -f 2 then nest --explode --values --across-fields -f 2 0*.tsv
```

you will have

```
abc     1       10      8       4
def     3       4       5       2
ghi     5       7       1       1
```

Comment: I got error, mlr option -N is not recognized

Comment: @Lulu'Nisrina you have -N option in Miller version >= 5.5.0. What's your output of `mlr --version`?

Comment: my mlr option is 5.3.0 that's why -N option is not recognized